# Average over rows pairs and paste the value based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I have a df such as:

```
     a      b   c 
 1   124    70  aa     
 2   129    67  aa     
 3   139    71  aa     
 4   125    77  aa     
 5   125    82  aa     
 6   121    69  aa     
 7   135    68  bb
 8   137    72  bb
 9   137    78  bb
10   140    86  bb
```

I want to iterate along rows within columns (a, b), computing the mean of all rows pairs, and paste this mean to the same two rows of new columns (a_new, b_new) if the difference between these two rows is >=12. Otherwise just copy the old value. This behaviour should be restricted to groups as marked by another column (c), i.e it should not happen if two rows are from different groups.

In this example, it happens in row 3 (cos in column a, difference with next (4th) row is 14) and in row 5 (cos in column b, difference with next row is 13). However, this should not happen with row 6 cos row 7 is in another c group.

Thus, resulting df would look like:

```
     a      b   c     a_new  b_new
 1   124    70  aa    124    70
 2   129    67  aa    129    67
 3   139    71  aa    132    71   
 4   125    77  aa    132    68
 5   125    82  aa    125    75.5
 6   121    69  aa    121    75.5
 7   135    68  bb    135    68
 8   137    72  bb    137    72
 9   137    78  bb    137    78
10   140    86  bb    140    86
```

I've been struggling to do this for a while, figured out that perhaps lag function could be used, but no success. Help would be much appreciated (be it base R, or dplyr, or whatever)

---

Dput:

```
structure(list(a = c(124, 129, 139, 125, 125, 121, 135, 137, 
137, 140), b = c(70, 67, 71, 77, 82, 69, 68, 72, 78, 86), c = c("aa", 
"aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I do not understand why 4th row in `a` is replaced nor do I get your exact values but do you mean something like this ? `df %>%
  group_by(c) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a, b), list(new = ~replace(., which(abs(diff(.)) >= 12) + 1, mean(.))))` ?

Comment: This seems to detect rows all right, but pasted values don't look like means and are only pasted to the second row of respective pair?

Comment: I am not clear about the logic here. The replacement has to be done by groups i.e `c`? Which rows do you replace and with what value?

Comment: I want to replace BOTH rows of which difference is >=12, with their mean. Hence e.g. I should get mean of row 3 (value: 139) and row 4 (value:125) pasted to row 3 and 4 of column a_new (and this mean is 132). This behaviour should not happen between rows belonging to different groups (column c), hence nothing happens with row 6 and 7 in column a_new (difference is >=12 but row 6 is in group 'aa' and row 7 is in group 'bb').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function which works for one chunk.

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
    inds <- which(abs(diff(x)) >= 12)
    if(length(inds))
        x[sort(c(inds, inds + 1))] <-  c(sapply(inds, function(i) 
                                          rep(mean(x[c(i, i + 1)]), 2)))
    return(x)
}
```

and then apply it for multiple columns by group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(c) %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b), list(new = apply_fun))

#      a     b c     a_new b_new
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   124    70 aa      124  70  
# 2   129    67 aa      129  67  
# 3   139    71 aa      132  71  
# 4   125    77 aa      132  77  
# 5   125    82 aa      125  75.5
# 6   121    69 aa      121  75.5
# 7   135    68 bb      135  68  
# 8   137    72 bb      137  72  
# 9   137    78 bb      137  78  
#10   140    86 bb      140  86
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is to apply to each group given by the indicator column "c" the procedure commented in the code below:

```
pairAverage <- function(x) {
  # x should be a numeric vector of length > 1
  if (is.vector(x) & is.numeric(x) & length(x) > 1) {

    # copy data to an aux vector
    aux <- x

    # get differences of lag 1
    dh<-diff(x, 1)

    # get means of consecutive pairs
    med <- c(x$a[2:length(x)] - dh/2)

    # get positions (index) of abs(means) >= 12  
    idx <- match(med[abs(dh) >= 12], med)

    # need 2 reps of each mean to replace consecutive values of x
    valToRepl <- med[sort(rep(idx,2))]

    # ordered indexes pairs of consecutive elements of x to be replaced  
    idxToRepl <- sort(c(idx,idx+1))

    # replace pairs of values 
    aux[idxToRepl] <- valToRepl

    return(aux)

  } else {
    # do nothing
    warning("paramater x should be a numeric vector of length > 1")
    return(NULL)
  }
}

pairAverageByGroups <- function(x, gr) {
  if (is.vector(x) & is.numeric(x) & length(x) == length(gr)) {
    x.ls <- split(x, as.factor(gr))
    output <- unlist(lapply(x.ls, pairAverage))
    names(output) <- NULL
    output
  } else {
    # do nothing
    warning("paremater x should be a numeric vector of length > 1")
    return(NULL)
  }
}

pairAverageByGroups(dd$a, dd$c)
 [1] 124 129 132 132 125 121 135 137 137 140
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I keep getting an error: 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'dd' not found'. dd seems to be used in the function, but name of my dataframe actually varies. I'm also getting weird prompt 'Browse[1]>', not sure why is that?

Comment: Sorry! I replace dd by x in the line ```med <- c(dd$a[2:length(x)] - dh/2)```. Try it now, the problem was that I wrote the funcion copying and pasting test code. dd was my data.frame name